# Swift: My UINavigationBar's background image is spreading too far down

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Here is my code for my Navigation Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "top_splash")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .Stretch), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    }
```

However, my background image spreads over my first view in the storyboard, and I cannot see it anymore. Here is an image of what it looks like:[image]

As you can see, the nav bar almost doubles in size to accomadate this picture. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `top_splash` was too big to start with. You can stretch an image a `resizableImage` but you can't compress it. Start with an image that is smaller than the standard height of the navigation bar (44 points) and all will be well.

Alternatively, you could set the nav bar's `clipsToBounds` to `true`, but then other bad things would happen — for example, it wouldn't stretch up behind the status bar correctly.

Comment: If I plan to make my app for iPad's in landscape, how big will the uinavigationBar be?

Comment: It doesn't matter, does it? As long as your image is smaller, it will stretch bigger. The problem is that it will never be made _smaller_ than it is to start with.

Comment: It does, I want to resize my image without losing a lot of quality

Comment: Well, I would say start with 32 points and see what happens. But if the status bar is going to be present, maybe you could do 32+20 = 52. Give it a try...